# Declaring SKSpriteNode outside spawn function returns SIGABRT in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, sigabrt

I have a game that I am making where I have a player and an unlimited number of enemies that's spawn at a given position in a certain amount of time. These enemies are shooting bullets at the player. I need to be able to access the Enemy variable outside the SpawnEnemies() function so that I can use it in my SpawnBullets() function. I tried declaring the Enemy variable outside the SpawnEnemies() function but it returned Sigabrt and I don't know how to access the Enemy variable outside the function without getting this error.

Enemy declaration:

```
var Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy.png")
```

SpawnEnemies function:

```
func SpawnEnemies() {
     let MinValue = self.size.width/8
     let MaxValue = self.size.width-20
     let SpawnPoint =  UInt32(MaxValue-MinValue)
     self.Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
     let action = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 3.0)
     self.Enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
     self.addChild(Enemy)

}
```

SpawnBullets function:

```
func SpawnBullets(){
     let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")
     Bullet.zPosition = -5
     Bullet.position = CGPointMake(Enemy.position.x, Enemy.position.y)
     let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 1.0)
     Bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
     self.addChild(Bullet)
}
```

Call SpawnEnemies function in didMoveToView():

```
var EnemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnEnemies"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Call SpawnBullets function in didMoveToView():

```
var BulletTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I get this error which is a sigabrt but I used a breakpoint to figure out exactly where the error was and what it was:

> Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Enemy.png' (60 x 80)] position:{132, 1024} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{60, 80} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00

Comment: you are adding the same Enemy to the GameScene more than once which is causing the error.  I wouldn't use an array though as that would limit the number of enemies you can have.  you might want to create an enemy class.  when you create a new instance of the enemy class it can spawn the enemy sprite and create a timer to spawn bullets based on location of itself.

Comment: The point of the game is so that the enemies spawn every second shooting bullets and the game goes on forever until the player dies however I did not get that far yet

Comment: I get that. I still suggest making an enemy class and create a new instance of it based on your enemy timer. The way you have it now is you have one enemy variable. You can't add the same variable to the gamescene more than once because it's already there.

Comment: I am new to swift can you posted answer and Actually show me how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding children to a scene already is "infinite", you just need to use it to your advantage.

First rework your bullet function like this so that you are passing in an enemy.

```
func SpawnBullets(enemy : SKSpriteNode){
     let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")
     Bullet.zPosition = -5
     Bullet.position = CGPointMake(enemy.position.x, enemy.position.y)
     let action = SKAction.moveToY(-self.size.height - 70, duration: 1.0)
     Bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
     self.addChild(Bullet) 
}
```

Then rework your enemy function so that overtime you call it you spawn a new enemy.

```
func SpawnEnemies() {
     var Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy.png")
     Enemy.name =  "enemy";
     let MinValue = self.size.width/8
     let MaxValue = self.size.width-20
     let SpawnPoint =  UInt32(MaxValue-MinValue)
     Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
     let action = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 3.0)
     Enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
     self.addChild(Enemy)

}
```

In the function didMoveToView, lets add actions to the scene that handles our timing so that we do not use NSTimer

```
{
...
  let spawnEnemy = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(
  {
    [unowned self] in 
    self.SpawnEnemies();
  }),SKAction.waitForDuration(1)]);

  let spawnBullet = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(
  {
    [unowned self] in
      self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy", usingBlock: 
      {
        (enemy : SKNode,stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) in
                   self.SpawnBullets(enemy as! SKSpriteNode);  
      });        
  }),SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)]);

  let group = SKAction.group([spawnEnemy, spawnBullet])
  self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(group))


}
```

This code is not tested so let me know if I need to update anything.

Comment: I will try it today and let you know

Comment: will this not make all enemies on screen fire a bullet at the same time?

Comment: @Steve from what I am seeing in his code, that is what he is trying to do

Comment: that is true @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Every enemy on the screen should fire a bullet that is what I want I haven't tested it yet how would I make it do that?

Comment: @StevenCassidy, the code I provided does that, basically every .2 seconds, it is spawning an enemy, and spawning bullets.  Now if you do not kill these nodes, you will run out of memory

Comment: If they go off the screen won't they be killed automatically and what if I want enemies spawn every second and the bullets to spawn every .2 seconds

Comment: @StevenCassidy No, It will be removed from rendering, but will not be removed from the scene itself.  There are times where it makes sense to not have Sprites on the screen

Comment: So how do I make it so that they're killed when they go off the screen? The player which is not  shown  above is always on the screen. I already coded that part. The only time it is off the screen is it the player tilts their device too far because I use the accelerometer.

Comment: You need to figure that out,  that has been asked a million times on SO, find a solution that works best for you

Comment: Is there a setting in xcode that allows me to see the number of nodes when I run the simulator?

Comment: only nodes on screen,  you need to do a print(scene.children.count) to find out how many main nodes are on your scene (if your children have children, that wont be included)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I get Errors with this code where can I post a screenshot

Comment: just post the errors so I can see them, like I said it is untested

Comment: gotta be more descriptive, where is it pointing to,  you shouldnt even be using an sknode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon /Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:38:26: Use of unresolved identifier 'customActionWithDuration'
/Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:46:35: Value of type 'SKNode?' has no member 'Generator'

/Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:43:44: Incorrect argument label in call (have '_:actionBlock:', expected '_:queue:')

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that is why I want to a screen shot

Comment: or you could have pointed me to that first error,  I fixed the code

Comment: /Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:39:13: Cannot convert value of type '(GameScene!, CGFloat) -> Void' to expected argument type '(SKNode, CGFloat) -> Void'

/Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:46:35: Value of type 'SKNode?' has no member 'Generator'

/Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:44:13: Cannot convert value of type '(GameScene!, CGFloat) -> Void' to expected argument type '(SKNode, CGFloat) -> Void'

Comment: @Knight0fDragon one error left /Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:48:36: Value of type 'SKNode?' has no member 'Generator'

Comment: /Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:48:36: error: value of type 'SKNode?' has no member 'Generator'                      for enemy in scene.childNodeWithName("enemy")
                    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ it is pointing to childNodeWithName

Comment: Unwrap it. scene!.child

Comment: Value of type 'SKNode?' has no member 'Generator' what does this even mean?

Comment: I see it. Its because childnamed is returning an sknode. Let me get home ill check the docs,  i thought that pulled all children

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  ERROR: /Users/Steven/Desktop/Projects/Mobile Apps/SkyShooter/iOS/SkyShooter/SkyShooter/GameScene.swift:50:120: Cannot convert value of type 'SKNode' to expected argument type 'SKSpriteNode'

Comment: oh we just need to cast enemy

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  Cannot convert value of type 'SKNode' to expected argument type 'SKSpriteNode' (enemy : SKNode,stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) in                   scene.SpawnBullets(enemy);

Comment: No errors but it does not work correctly tons of enemies and bullets spawn  on the screen the enemies are not shooting the bullets the old way I had it the enemies spawn nice and slowly I need to take a screen capture video to show you what it looks like I will put it on YouTube and show you the link

Comment: yeah just change the time that enemy spawns at,  I have it set at .2, just change it to 1

Comment: if you do not remove enemies they will keep firing

Comment: @Knight0fDragon used to look like before bullets: https://youtu.be/uqEUXEzFYZE nice and slow

Comment: I don't even see bullets in your second video.  You need to define what logic you want.  Right now the code says spawn a enemy every second, for every enemy, spawn a  bullet every .2 seconds

Comment: if you put the spawn enemy code in your update function then you have no idea what is going

Comment: I have it that way why are there so many enemies and also the bullets don't even look like they're being shot from the enemy and yes that's what it looked like the old way before I added bullets

Comment: oh duh hold on,  the custom action is not what we want hold on

Comment: The only thing I have in the update function is a function for the orange player, and a function that moves the background

Comment: there we go,  now it is spawn an enemy every second, spawn bullets every .2 seconds

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The enemies are spawning correctly but not the bullets: https://youtu.be/TDzvmG0uHlo

Comment: Did you watch the video? They don't look like the enemy is shooting them they just look like they're spawning randomly on the screen

Comment: no, the enemies are shooting them, you just have enemies on the bottom of the screen that is firing them

Comment: you're not killing the enemies off the screen so they are all firing bullets too.  That looks like what you asked for

Comment: I know I have to do that but it shouldn't affect how it looks because the enemies are supposed to be firing in the direction they're going which means once they pass the player and you go off the screen you shouldn't the bullets anymore

Comment: are you saying the bullets should be firing down?

Comment: Yes they should be and as the enemy moves down the screen it should look like they're shooting at the player

Comment: well that's because you have them firing up, that's your code you need to fix

Comment: btw, for bullets you shouldn't use moveTo, you should use moveBy, otherwise, as your enemy travels down more, the bullets move slower up (You want the enemy to fire down now, so this means as the enemy moves down, the bullets move faster)

Comment: Okay I kind of got it but one more thing sometimes a bullet shoots that isn't in line with an enemy because it is being shot before the enemy appears on the screen how can I make it so bullets are not fired by specific enemy until it is on the screen and also it looks like each enemy is only spawning one bullet I tried to change the duration but that didn't work how can I make it so bullets are spawned continuously: https://youtu.be/kEZyxIvq7fU

Comment: the code already makes them fire continuously. your video showed that.  You want them to fire when on screen then you need to change the logic,  everything is done in your spawn bullet function

Comment: So by changing moveTo to moveBy it will make my bullets spawn faster and to make sure that it only happens when the bullets are on the screen use a conditional if

Comment: changing moveto to moveby makes the bullets travel at a consistent speed

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Could I add a conditional to make sure that the enemies do not fire until they can be seen?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon With the old code the bullets did not move in the right direction now they do I tested it myself